# rails rspec how to know if method is called from worker perform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I hav this worker

```
class Aworker
  def perform(x_id)
    method_c
  end

  def method_c
   # ...
  end
```

and in my spec file

```
RSpec.describe Aworker, type: :worker do
  describe ".perform" do
  x = FactoryBot.create(:x)
  expect(described_class.new.perform(x.id))to receive(method_c)
  end
end
```

but I get this error:
ArgumentError:
Cannot proxy frozen objects, rspec-mocks relies on proxies for method stubbing and expectations.

I have followed some tutorials but I'm not sure if workers are tested differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should look something like that:

```rb
RSpec.describe Aworker, type: :worker do
  describe ".perform" do
    it 'performs' do
      x = FactoryBot.create(:x)
      instance = described_class.new
      expect(instance).to receive(:method_c)
      instance.perform(x.id)
    end
  end
end
```